# Convert incremental grid index to (x,y) coordinates

Tags: algorithm, math, layout, formula, algebra

I'm desperately looking for the expressions giving me `x` and `y` for each `i`, ordered in this manner:

[image: grid to coordinates]

```
x = f(i) ??
y = f(i) ??
```

I'm coding in GLSL so I have access to basic math functions (modulo, floor, square root...) as well as if/else statements. I only have access to the `i` variable though.

Comment: @RoryDaulton yes for both, I edited my question as such. Programming code is fine to me, but the best answer would be an inline expression (probably involving ternary operators...).

Comment: There's no point making things more compact and harder to read than they should be. I'd recommend creating a function and just calling that, unless there's some particular reason to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know GLSL but here is code in Python 3. This should be easy to convert to other languages. (You could use `floor` rather than `int` here.) This version uses Python to return two output values `x` and `y` for one input value `i`. In Python 3 the line `from math import sqrt` would be needed at the top of the code.

```
def f(i):
    base = int(sqrt(i))
    remains = i - base * base
    if remains <= base:
        x = remains
        y = base
    else:
        x = base
        y = 2 * base - remains
    return x, y
```